# zend framework 2 plugin predispatch

Tags: zend-framework2

In ZF 1 we created a predispatch function in a controller plugin class
such as
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Re­quest_Abstract $request) {
Can we create the same predispatch function in ZF2 ? How ?
Please Advice .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[See here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/zend-framework-2-controllerpluginmanager-append-controller-pluginto-all-controller/)**
It's not pre dispath but the effect is similar.